# IMX fsl_micfil driver hang because DMA is not available yet

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma, imx8

I'm working on an embedded device based on an NXP i.MX8M mini SoC.  It is running Linux based on NXP's "hardknott" Yocto recipe: https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-manifest/tree/imx-5.10.52-2.1.0.xml?h=imx-linux-hardknott

Here's the bitbake script for the kernel it is using: https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/meta-imx/tree/meta-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux?h=hardknott-5.10.52-2.1.0

I believe it is pulling the kernel sources from here: https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/linux-imx/tree/?h=lf-5.10.y

Our device has a digital microphone that is being driven by a modified version of NXP's `fsl_micfil.c` driver: https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/linux-imx/tree/sound/soc/fsl/fsl_micfil.c?h=lf-5.10.y

Our modifications are:

- In `fsl_micfil_hw_params`, where their code does "enable channels" (around line 1592), we've changed it to only enable the channel we care about instead of all of them.

  We changed:

  ```
  ret = regmap_update_bits(micfil->regmap, REG_MICFIL_CTRL1,
                           0xFF, ((1 << channels) - 1));
  ```

  To:

  ```
  ret = regmap_update_bits(micfil->regmap, REG_MICFIL_CTRL1,
                           0xFF, 1 << 6);
  ```
- At the start of `fsl_micfil_probe` (around line 2202), we add code to pull a GPIO line (the mic's enable line) low.  If GPIO isn't available at the time, we return `-EPROBE_DEFER` in order to try again later
- Further down in `fsl_micfil_probe` (around line 2334), we change the DMA channel from 0 to 6 (to align with our enable change).

  We changed:

  ```
  micfil->dma_params_rx.addr = res->start + REG_MICFIL_DATACH0;
  ```

  To:

  ```
  micfil->dma_params_rx.addr = res->start + REG_MICFIL_DATACH6;
  ```

That having been described, here's the problem.

Our application is trying to read audio from this microphone (we can test it with the `arecord` command).

We have found that if we launch our application immediately after Linux boots, the device hangs.  We need to power-cycle it to recover.

If we wait about 60 seconds after bootup, however, we see the following messages appear on the console:

```
[   60.386133] imx-sdma 302c0000.dma-controller: firmware found.
[   60.392010] imx-sdma 302c0000.dma-controller: loaded firmware 4.6
```

If we launch our application after these messages appear, everything works fine.

I looked through the implementation of the `imx-sdma` driver: https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/linux-imx/tree/drivers/dma/imx-sdma.c?h=lf-5.10.y

The driver loads some kind of firmware when it starts up.  The first message ("firmware found") is presented by the probe function.  The second ("loaded firmware") is presented by one of the two power management resume functions (`sdma_resume` or `sdma_runtime_resume`).

So it appears that the problem is that this DMA driver is not loading until the system has been running for about 60 seconds.  I assume this is due to some kind of lazy initialization that waits until some kernel driver requires access.  And my problem is happening because my driver requires access and is initializing before the DMA driver has loaded.

So, what's a good fix for this?  I assume I need to add something to the `fsl_micfil` driver to request startup of the DMA driver.  But I don't know how to do this and I don't actually know if that is the correct fix for this problem.

What would you suggest as a proper fix for this bug?

(FWIW, we made very similar changes to an older version of the kernel - based on Yocto's "sumo" branch, running kernel 4.14, and there are no problems there.  So clearly something changed between kernel 4.14 and 5.10 that our code needs to deal with, but I don't know what that might be.)

Comment: You're not clear: is there a problem without the changes you made? Btw calling a "hang" a "crash" (aka panic) is confusing. Rather than just knowing the circumstances to trigger the problem, perhaps you should investigate where/why the "*device*" hangs before coming up with a fix.

Comment: The device hangs and become inoperable.  We don't see any kernel panic data.  But the problem does not occur after we see the message about the imx-sdma driver loading.

Comment: Your comment really does not add any new information.  Do you have a serial console?  Have you captured/logged the the boot messages?  Have you added **printk()** messages to see the progress of each (DMAC & audio) driver?  FWIW firmware loading is also common for USB WiFi adapters.  A userspace app (e..g. **Busybox**) performs the file retrieval on behalf of the kernel driver's request.

Comment: FYI, I did build and deploy a kernel with the unmodified audio driver.  Same issue (and no audio if we wait for the DMA driver to load, which I expected).  We contacted NXP and they think the late-loading of their DMA driver (which they confirmed) is a bug on their part, so maybe it will be fixed that way.

Comment: You misuse/over-use "*load*" in a similar way you did "*crash*".  That would be a (completion of) initialization issue, rather than a "*load*".  For drivers that a built-in the kernel image, why would they be "*loaded*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out the reason (but not the best solution) for the problem.

As I wrote in the original message, the `micfil` driver uses `imx-sdma`, which tries to load firmware from the file system.

The "Sumo" (kernel 4.14) branch has no problem with this.  At the time the driver starts, the root file system has been mounted (read-only), so it has no problem loading its firmware.

With the "Hardknott" (kernel 5.10) and "Kirkstone" (kernel 5.15) branches, however, the SDMA driver tries to load very very early in the boot sequence - before any file systems have mounted.  So direct loading fails.  It then posts an event via `udev`, to request that user-space code provide the firmware via `sysfs`.  But the driver appears to be starting so early (within 10-15 ms, according to `dmesg`) that `udev` isn't able to queue up the event.  I'm not sure about the specific reason why but debugging shows that the event is never delivered to user space.

The kernel side of the `udev` request times out after 60 seconds, at which point the driver retries the request, which succeeds because all the file systems are fully mounted by that point.

An ideal fix would be to modify the `imx-sdma` driver so it doesn't start until after the file system mounts, so it can directly load its firmware.  Or at minimum, after `udev` is ready and able to deliver the firmware-load event to user space.  I let NXP know about this issue, so maybe they'll fix it in a future release of their driver.

Until that happens, my workaround is to change the kernel configuration so the `imx-sdma` driver is compiled as a loadable module.  This means it can't load and start until after the root file system is available, at which point it has no problem finding its firmware.  `dmesg` shows that this happens about 6s into the boot sequence - later than I'd prefer, but early enough that no application software has started running, so nothing hangs or crashes.